# Efficient way of keeping numbers in order

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, sorting, computer-science

This is a problem that could apply to any language, but I'll use python to show it.

Say you have a list of numbers, `ls = [0,100,200,300,400]`

You can insert an element at any index, but the elements must always stay in numerical order. Duplicates are not allowed.

For example, `ls.insert(2, 150)` results in `ls = [0,100,150,200,300,400]`. The elements are in the correct order, so this is correct.

However, `ls.insert(3, 190)` results in `ls = [0,100,200,190,300,400]`. This is incorrect.

**For any index `i`, what is the best number `x` to use in `ls.insert(i,x)` to minimize the number of sorts?**

My first intuition was to add half the difference between the previous and next numbers to the previous one. So to insert a number at index 3, `x` would equal 200 + (300-200), or 250. However this approaches the asymptote far too quickly. When the differences get too close to 0, I could restore the differences by looping through and changing each number to produce a larger difference. I want to choose the best number for `x` so to minimize the number of times I need to reset.

**EDIT**

The specific problem I'm applying this to is a iOS app with a list view. The items in the list are represented in a Set, and each object has an attribute orderingValue. I can't use an Array to represent the list (due to issues with cache-server syncing), so I have to sort the set each time I display the list to the user. In order to do this, the orderingValue must be stored on the ListItem object.

One additional detail is, due to the nature of the UI, the user is probably more likely to add an item to the top or bottom of the list rather than insert it in the middle.

Comment: Since the exact values of the integers apparently doesn't matter at all, why have them to begin with? What data are you actually storing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you want a list of n distinct integer values, range(n) will work in python.

Comment: The arithmetic mean seems like the best choice. Anything else will make the worst case worse.

Comment: You need to know what the number of indexes are going to be. This problem sounds a lot like resizing dictionaries to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate sort keys indefinitely if you use strings rather than integers. That's because a lexicographical ordering of strings puts an infinite number of values between any two strings (as long as the larger isn't the smaller one followed by `"a"`).

Here's a function to generate a lowercase string key between two other keys:

```
def get_key_str(low="a", high="z"):
    if low == "":
        low = "a"
    assert(low < high)
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(low, high)):
        if a < b:
            mid = chr((ord(a) + ord(b))//2) # get the character half-way between a and b
            if mid != a:
                return low[:i] + mid
            else:
                return low[:i+1] + get_key_str(low[i+1:], "z")
    return low + get_key_str("a", high[len(low):])
```

It always returns a string `s` such that `"a" <= low < s < high <= "z"`. `"a"` and `"z"` are never used themselves as keys, they're special values to indicate the boundaries of the possible results.

You'd call it with `get_key_str([lst[i-1], lst[i])` to get a value to insert before the value at index `i`. You can insert and generate a value in one go with `lst.insert(i, get_key_str(lst[i-1], lst[i]))`. Obviously though, the ends of the list need special handling.

The default values are set so that you can omit an argument to get a value to insert at the start or the end. That is, call `get_key_str(high=lst[0])` to get a value to put at the start of your list or `get_key_str(lst[-1])` to get a value to append to at the end. You can also explicitly pass `"a"` as `low` or `"z"` as `high`, if that's easier. With no arguments, it will return `"m"`, which is a reasonable first value to put in an empty list.

It's possible that you could tune this a bit to give shorter keys when you're mostly adding at the start or end, but that would be a bit more complicated. This version should have its keys grow roughly evenly if you're inserting randomly.

Here's an example of doing some random inserts:

```
>>> import random
>>> lst = []
>>> for _ in range(10):
    index = random.randint(0, len(lst))
    print("inserting at", index)
    if index == 0:
        low = "a"
    else:
        low = lst[index-1]
    if index == len(lst):
        high = "z"
    else:
        high = lst[index]
    lst.insert(index, get_key_str(low, high))
    print(lst)


inserting at 0
['m']
inserting at 1
['m', 's']
inserting at 2
['m', 's', 'v']
inserting at 2
['m', 's', 't', 'v']
inserting at 2
['m', 's', 'sm', 't', 'v']
inserting at 0
['g', 'm', 's', 'sm', 't', 'v']
inserting at 3
['g', 'm', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v']
inserting at 2
['g', 'm', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v']
inserting at 2
['g', 'm', 'n', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v']
inserting at 3
['g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v']
```

And here's how it behaves if we then do a bunch of inserts at the start and end:

```
>>> for _ in range(10):
    lst.insert(0, get_key_str(high=lst[0]))  # start
    lst.insert(len(lst), get_key_str(low=lst[-1])) # end
    print(lst)


['d', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x']
['b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y']
['am', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'ym']
['ag', 'am', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'ym', 'ys']
['ad', 'ag', 'am', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'ym', 'ys', 'yv']
['ab', 'ad', 'ag', 'am', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'ym', 'ys', 'yv', 'yx']
['aam', 'ab', 'ad', 'ag', 'am', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'ym', 'ys', 'yv', 'yx', 'yy']
['aag', 'aam', 'ab', 'ad', 'ag', 'am', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'ym', 'ys', 'yv', 'yx', 'yy', 'yym']
['aad', 'aag', 'aam', 'ab', 'ad', 'ag', 'am', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'ym', 'ys', 'yv', 'yx', 'yy', 'yym', 'yys']
['aab', 'aad', 'aag', 'aam', 'ab', 'ad', 'ag', 'am', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 's', 'sg', 'sm', 't', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'ym', 'ys', 'yv', 'yx', 'yy', 'yym', 'yys', 'yyv']
```

So at the start you may end up with keys prefixed by `a`s, and at the end you'll get keys prefixed by `y`s.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Now, it was probably a mistake for me to ask the question in python, since my end goal is to use the solution in Objective-C. I'll work on translating the technique, but I may be back with additional questions. Thanks again for the very thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

As far as the 'best' value is concerned, it is always going to be halfway through the previous and the next element. And it is going to reach the asymptote.

One way to delay arrival at the asymptote if there are repeated insertions at a particular index is to decrement the previous and increment the next value (I'm assuming you are allowed to do this) every time you perform the insert.

So, for `ls.insert(2,150)`, after insertion

```
ls[1] = ls[1] - (ls[1] - ls[0])/2
ls[3] = ls[3] + (ls[4] - ls[3])/2
```

For every other insertion, this rule will hold, and assuming insertions are at random indices, you would have a fair amount of time before you need to increase each number's value.

Also, the moment you encounter two adjacent numbers with a difference of 1, you would, of course, have to loop through the numbers and increase them.